# Solve $x^3 +3x -4 =0$ in Real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve $x^3 +3x -4 =0$ in Real Numbers.

I know the answer is 1 but i want the solution. if you solve it with decomposition, explain how did you find what to do to decompose this expression. (I know the Decomposition but first I find 1 with testing some numbers for x and then by dividing the expression, I find the decomposition but I want a solution that doesn't need testing numbers).

Comment: Since the sum of the coefficients of such a polynomial is zero, it is quite trivial that $x=1$ is a root.

Comment: There is a way to solve an arbitrary cubic without "testing numbers" but it is long and complicated to explain.  Read more [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#General_formula_for_roots).

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, it is easy to see that $x=1$ is a root.

The derivative of $x^3 +3x -4$ is $3x^2 +3$ which is never zero for $x$ real.
Therefore $f(x)=x^3 +3x -4$ is strictly increasing and so $x=1$ is the only real root.

Answer (score 3):

note that $$x^3+3x-4=(x-1)(x^2+x+4)$$

Comment: I know the decomposition, I want to know how to get this decomposition, step by step.

Comment: @titansarus That's polynomial long division. Google it.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I wanted to solve it without knowing the roots.Just finding the decomposition. someone mentioned in the comments a wikipedia page with the general way to solve this expressions. Thanks Everyone.

Comment: @titansarus No. No. No. No. No. No. No. No. No. You do not use the cubic formula to solve a cubic polynomial. That is the worst possible approach you can choose to take. Look up the rational roots test; I suspect that's what you want. I sincerely doubt you're actually looking for the general solution to a cubic.

Answer (score 2):

For this, I would just factor out an $x-1$. So $x^3+3x-4=(x-1)(x^2+x+4)$. Thus trivially $x=1$ is a real root, and via the quadratic formula (or your method of choice) on the term $x^2+x+4$ you find two other complex roots, but that's not what you wanted so just take the real root.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:-

> Use **factor theorem** which states that $(x-n)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ if $f(n)=0$.

Putting $f(1)$ in your polynomial $f(x)=x^3+3x-4$ gives $0$.

Hence $(x-1)$ is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=u+v$, then $(u+v)^3+3(u+v)-4=0$

$u^3+v^3+3(u+v)(uv+1)=4$

We have one degree of freedom in choosing $u$ or $v$.

Take $uv+1=0$

Now $\displaystyle v=-\frac{1}{u}$ and 
$\displaystyle u^3+v^3=4 \implies u^3-\frac{1}{u^{3}}=4$

$u^6-4u^3-1=0 \implies u^{3}=2\pm \sqrt{5}$

$\displaystyle (u,v)=
\left( \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2} , \frac{1\mp \sqrt{5}}{2} \right) \implies x=1$

Answer (score 1):

Use Cardan's Method to solve cubic

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kkreith/tutorials/sample.lesson/cardano.html

Also since you know 1 is real root of equation, you can use synthetic division to find other one's

Answer (score 1):

> *Hint:* It is sometimes helpful to give the *[integer root theorem](http://www.themathpage.com/aprecalc/factor-theorem.htm#integer)* a try. Since the polynomial 
>   \begin{align*}
> p(x)=x^3+3x-4
> \end{align*}
>   has integral coefficients with $1$ beeing the coefficient of the highest degree, we conclude that *if* there are integer roots they will divide $-4$, the coefficient of $x^0$.

So, possible candidates are $\pm1,\pm2,\pm4$ from which we obtain already by the first try
\begin{array}{cccc}
p(1)=\color{blue}{0}
\end{array}

> Since $1$ is an integer root with $p(1)=0$, we can continue with factorization and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> p(x)&=x^3+3x-4\\
> &=(x-1)(x^2+x+4)
> \end{align*}
>   The other roots are those of the quadratic polynomial and can be found using standard techniques.

According to the hint from @user1952009 we see that the *[discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant)* $\Delta$ of the quadratic polynomial $x^2+x+4$ is $$\Delta=b^2-4ac=1-16<0$$ So,  both solutions are not real numbers, leaving $1$ the only real solution.

Comment: $x^2+x + 4 =0$, $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 1-16 < 0$ so it has two complex roots

Comment: @user1952009: Hint incorporated. Thanks!